# How do you determine filesystem availability from a bash script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, filesystems, fuse

If I have a script that relies on one of the following being present: overlayfs, aufs, unionfs - what is the best way to determine which is available from a bash script?  I would like to use overlayfs, but fall back to aufs or unionfs if it is not available.  I can look at the kernel version as a guess - but just because it's a >= 3.18 kernel doesn't mean that overlayfs was built in - is there a reasonably foolproof way to check?

Comment: easiest way, lsmod and analyzing the output of modprobe, no? I am interested in knowing better ways too, will be modding up this question.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest e. g. `if modprobe | grep -q 'fs_aufs'; then echo "aufs is present"; fi`.

Comment: I don't know much about aufs, but it could be compiled into the kernel as opposed to being a module.

Comment: This is true - it's more typical to be a module, but you can't count on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under Linux, you can see which filesystem types are available in the running kernel in the file `/proc/filesystems`. The content of this file is built in real time by the kernel when it's read, so it reflects the current status. The format of this file is a bit annoying: each line contains either 8 spaces followed by a filesystem type, or `nodev` followed by 3 spaces followed by a filesystem type. Strip off the first 8 characters of each line to get just the available filesystem types, or use `grep -w` (as long as you aren't looking for a filesystem type called `nodev`).

```
if grep -qw aufs /proc/filesystems; then
  echo aufs is available
fi
```

This isn't the complete story, because the filesystem driver could be available in the form of a module that isn't currently loaded. Assuming you can load modules, if the filesystem isn't available, try loading it. Filesystem modules have an alias of the form `fs-FSTYPE` (the actual module name is often the name of the filesystem type, but not always).

```
if grep -qw aufs /proc/filesystems; then
  echo aufs is available
elif modprobe fs-aufs; then
  echo now aufs is available
fi
```

This is for kernel filesystems. For FUSE filessytems, check whether the `fuse` filesystem is available, and look for the executable that implements the filesystem. While you can look for `fuse` in `/proc/filesystems`, that only tells you whether it's available, not whether your program has enough privileges to use it. A more reliable test in practice is to check whether you can write to `/dev/fuse`.

```
if [ -w /dev/fuse ]; then
  echo FUSE is available
  if type unionfs-fuse >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then 
    echo unionfs-fuse is available
  fi
fi
```